# Using a specific column to populate tooltips in Bokeh

Tags: python, anaconda, bokeh

Consider the following scatter plot example. 
I have a dataframe `df` with three columns: `colA`, `colB` and `colC`. I would like to do a scatterplot of `df` so that the tooltip shows the values of `colC`.

I tried:

```
import bokeh
from bokeh.charts import Scatter, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool

p = Scatter(df, x='colA', y='colB', title="Foo", color="navy",
            xlabel="A", ylabel="B", tools="hover")

hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips = [("C", "$colC")]
hover.mode = 'mouse'
output_file("scatter.html")
show(p)
```

but `C` always shows as `????` in the tooltip. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` syntax is only for a [few specific special pre-defined variables](http://doc.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tools.html#bokeh.models.tools.HoverTool.tooltips). You want to use `@foo` to reference a generic column in a data source:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

p = figure(tools="hover")

p.circle(x='colA', y='colB', title="Foo", color="navy", source=df)

p.hover.tooltips = [("C", "@colC")]
p.hover.mode = 'mouse'

output_file("scatter.html")
show(p)
```

See, e.g. http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#hovertool